# Motivation to define a norm for matrix whereas it's not bounded.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Could someone explain me the motivation to define a norm on matrix whereas linear applications are not bounded. The norm I know is for example 
$$\|A\|=\sup\{|\left<Ax,x\right>|\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}.$$
Ok, I agree that $\{x\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}$ is bounded, but what is the interest to define such a norm in the unit disk ?

Comment: Because every vector is a scalar multiple of something on the unit disk (hint: divide by its norm)

Answer (score 0):

It lets you assign bounds to the impact of $A$. For example, if you know that $\|v - w\| < \delta$, then you also know that $\|Av - Aw\| < \|A\|\delta$.

For example, this is very useful in functional analysis, where you are performing calculus operations on linear spaces, and in numerical analysis, where you have to estimate error growth.